# Reduce complexity O^2 of comparison between list of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have two list of objects:

```
list1 = [{value: 'X'}, {value: 'Y'}, ..., {value: 'Z'}];
list2 = [{value: 'A'}, {value: 'B'}, ..., {value: 'C'}];
```

I have this code that checks whether the values in `list2` are in `list1`. If it is the code doesn't do anything, if not it should add to `list1` (this will create a new list, `list3`). Which means I'm doing a union between the two list without keeping the repeated values.

```
for (let i = list2.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  let item = list2[i];
  let shared = false;
  for (let j = list1.length-1; j >=0; j--) {
    let childItem = list1[j];
    if (item.value === childItem.value) {
      shared = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!shared) { newValues.push(item); }
}
list3 = list1.concat(newValues);
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if I could improve this O(n*m).

I'm not sure if the lists are always sorted by default, but from what I've seen both (list1 and list2) are always sorted by value.

Example:

```
var list1 = [{value: 'bar'}, {value: 'baz'}, {value: 'foo'}, {value: 'foz'}];
var list2 = [{value: 'bar'}, {value: 'foo'}, {value: 'test'}, {value: 'testz'}];
var list3 = union(list1, list2);
list3 = [{value: 'bar'}, {value: 'baz'}, {value: 'foo'}, {value: 'foz'}, {value: 'test'}, {value: 'testz'}];
```

Comment: When you say "whether the values in list2 are in list1" do you mean, if any, or if all, values?

Comment: I will add one example to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a set of the values of `list1`, and Filter `list2` by the values in the set before concating it to `list1`:

```js
var list1 = [{value: 'bar'}, {value: 'baz'}, {value: 'foo'}, {value: 'foz'}];
var list2 = [{value: 'bar'}, {value: 'foo'}, {value: 'test'}, {value: 'testz'}];

const union = (list1, list2) => list1.concat(
  list2.filter(function({ value }) { // filter list2
    return !this.has(value); // filter out items which value is in the set
  }, new Set(list1.map(({ value }) => value))) // the set of list1 values
);

const list3 = union(list1, list2);

console.log(list3);
```

Comment: The question was about improving the (worst case) complexity. How does your solution do in this regard and is it actually better in terms of asymptotic behavior?

Comment: So what is the improvement of your code compared to the one I posted? Is it because you don't create a temp list?

Comment: It's because I don't have a loop inside a loop, which gives you the O(n * m).
Creating a Set is O(2n). Filtering `list2` is O(m). Concating is O(n + m). So the overall complexity is O(3n + 2m), and we can remove the constants for O(n + m).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single loop and store the value in a set for later check. Complexity: O(n).

```js
var list1 = [{ value: 'X' }, { value: 'Y' }, { value: 'C' }, { value: 'Z' }],
    list2 = [{ value: 'A' }, { value: 'B' }, { value: 'C' }, { value: 'D' }],
    list3 = list1
        .concat(list2)
        .filter((s => ({ value }) => !s.has(value) && s.add(value))(new Set));

console.log(list3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Actually O(n + m) because you iterate list1 + list2

Comment: @OriDrori, for linear complexity, O(n) is sufficient to describe it.